# PostGIS generic vs specific geometry types

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geometry, performance

PostGIS expects a geometry type parameter when creating a Geometry column and permitted values include `GEOMETRY`, `POINT`, `POLYGON`, etc.

If I choose `GEOMETRY` then my Geometry column can store points, lines, polygons, etc, and if I choose `POLYGON` then the column can only store polygons. One obvious reason to use a specific geometry type such as `POLYGON` is to enforce a type constraint on insert / update.

Has anyone experienced performance gains from using a specific type over a generic type? For example, if I execute an ST_Intersects function against an equivalent number of `GEOMETRY` objects and `POLYGON` objects should I expect either operation to be faster?

To clarify - at this stage I'm only interested in PostGIS performance and I do not want to consider the cost of any additional complexity required in a database client that may need to handle each geometry type differently.

If I'm able to set aside some time I will attempt to test performance myself, but I would also like to hear anyone else's experience.

Comment: The *C* core types are encoded with the explicit geometry type, and most functions in PostGS do have to include a base check (against e.g. *GEOS*) to decide the most appropriate action for the compared geometry types. The index mechanics should not differ (much) between types themselves. I would expect most, if not all, available functions to perform equally on comparable data, no matter if the geometry *typemod* is specific or generic.

Comment: Accessing the data is also very important. For example, QGIS would scan every row of a geometry (generic) column when accessing it (adding the table, opening a project containing the said table, saving the project etc), while if the specific type+projection is set, the table is loaded directly. It can take several minutes to perform this validation... each time you touch the project/table

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PostGIS indexes and functions are all coded to handle arbitrary geometry types.  So there is no performance gain by using a more specific geometry typmod parameter.

Comment: can you point to any documentation or direct experience to back this up? I don't doubt the accuracy of the statement, but decisions based on this could have cascading consequences so it would be good to have some additional confidence on the matter.

Comment: This is base on my knowledge of the source code, and discussions with Paul Ramsey, the lead PostGIS developer and architect.  So it's pretty solid.